# nothing provides __cuda needed by tensorflow-2.10.0-cuda112py310he87a039_0

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, mamba, mambaforge

I'm using mambaforge on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 with `systemd` enabled. I'm trying to install TensorFlow 2.10 with CUDA enabled, by using the command:

```
mamba install tensorflow
```

And the command `nvidia-smi -q` from WSL2 gives:

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Sat Dec 17 23:22:43 2022
Driver Version                            : 527.56
CUDA Version                              : 12.0

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Product Name                          : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU
    Product Brand                         : GeForce
    Product Architecture                  : Ampere
    Display Mode                          : Disabled
    Display Active                        : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                      : Enabled
    MIG Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Accounting Mode                       : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000
    Driver Model
        Current                           : WDDM
        Pending                           : WDDM
    Serial Number                         : N/A
    GPU UUID                              : GPU-f03a575d-7930-47f3-4965-290b89514ae7
    Minor Number                          : N/A
    VBIOS Version                         : 94.04.3f.00.d7
    MultiGPU Board                        : No
    Board ID                              : 0x100
    Board Part Number                     : N/A
    GPU Part Number                       : 249D-750-A1
    Module ID                             : 1
    Inforom Version
        Image Version                     : G001.0000.03.03
        OEM Object                        : 2.0
        ECC Object                        : N/A
        Power Management Object           : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    GSP Firmware Version                  : N/A
    GPU Virtualization Mode
        Virtualization Mode               : None
        Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A
    IBMNPU
        Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                               : 0x01
        Device                            : 0x00
        Domain                            : 0x0000
        Device Id                         : 0x249D10DE
        Bus Id                            : 00000000:01:00.0
        Sub System Id                     : 0x118C1043
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                       : 3
                Current                   : 3
                Device Current            : 3
                Device Max                : 4
                Host Max                  : 3
            Link Width
                Max                       : 16x
                Current                   : 8x
        Bridge Chip
            Type                          : N/A
            Firmware                      : N/A
        Replays Since Reset               : 0
        Replay Number Rollovers           : 0
        Tx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
        Rx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
        Atomic Caps Inbound               : N/A
        Atomic Caps Outbound              : N/A
    Fan Speed                             : N/A
    Performance State                     : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                              : Active
        Applications Clocks Setting       : Not Active
        SW Power Cap                      : Not Active
        HW Slowdown                       : Not Active
            HW Thermal Slowdown           : Not Active
            HW Power Brake Slowdown       : Not Active
        Sync Boost                        : Not Active
        SW Thermal Slowdown               : Not Active
        Display Clock Setting             : Not Active
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                             : 8192 MiB
        Reserved                          : 159 MiB
        Used                              : 12 MiB
        Free                              : 8020 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                             : 8192 MiB
        Used                              : 1 MiB
        Free                              : 8191 MiB
    Compute Mode                          : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                               : 0 %
        Memory                            : 0 %
        Encoder                           : 0 %
        Decoder                           : 0 %
    Encoder Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    FBC Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    Ecc Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            SRAM Correctable              : N/A
            SRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
            DRAM Correctable              : N/A
            DRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
        Aggregate
            SRAM Correctable              : N/A
            SRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
            DRAM Correctable              : N/A
            DRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Double Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Pending Page Blacklist            : N/A
    Remapped Rows                         : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp                  : 46 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp                 : 101 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp                 : 98 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp            : 87 C
        GPU Target Temperature            : N/A
        Memory Current Temp               : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp         : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management                  : Supported
        Power Draw                        : 12.08 W
        Power Limit                       : 4294967.50 W
        Default Power Limit               : 80.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit              : 100.00 W
        Min Power Limit                   : 1.00 W
        Max Power Limit                   : 100.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                          : 210 MHz
        SM                                : 210 MHz
        Memory                            : 405 MHz
        Video                             : 555 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Deferred Clocks
        Memory                            : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                          : 2100 MHz
        SM                                : 2100 MHz
        Memory                            : 6001 MHz
        Video                             : 1950 MHz
    Max Customer Boost Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                        : N/A
        Auto Boost Default                : N/A
    Voltage
        Graphics                          : 637.500 mV
    Fabric
        State                             : N/A
        Status                            : N/A
    Processes
        GPU instance ID                   : N/A
        Compute instance ID               : N/A
        Process ID                        : 24
            Type                          : G
            Name                          : /Xwayland
            Used GPU Memory               : Not available in WDDM driver model
```

And my other enviroment works as expected:

```
⬢ [Systemd] ❯ mamba activate tf

~ via   tf via  774MiB/19GiB | 0B/5GiB
⬢ [Systemd] ❯ python
Python 3.9.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:45:29)
[GCC 10.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2022-12-17 23:25:13.867166: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

Then, it tries to install package version `cuda112py39h9333c2f_1`, winch uses Python 3.9, but I want Python 3.10. Whenever I try to install the version for 3.10, it shows the error:

```
Could not solve for environment specs
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides __cuda needed by tensorflow-2.10.0-cuda112py310he87a039_0

The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I solve it?

Comment: @merv added the info as requested

Comment: I'd note that Mamba's messaging for reporting unsolvable requests has a quirk that it reports the last thing rejected. Since it works from newest builds to oldest, it often reports a version that was outside your constraints (i.e., Python 3.9 build, when you have v3.10). While still better than Conda's conflict reporting, it's not great. Basically, just ignore the versions, and see that it can't find a satisfactory `tensorflow`, possibly because it's not detecting CUDA (`__cuda`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this today and found a solution that works (after also seeing your GitHub post). Long story short, you need to use `CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA` to make this work as described in this [conda-forge blog post](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2021-11-03-tensorflow-gpu/).

For example, with CUDA 11.8 and mamba, use:

`CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.8" mamba install tensorflow -c conda-forge`

For CUDA 11.8 and conda, it would be:

`CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.8" conda install tensorflow -c conda-forge`

Depending on your setup, you may also want to install cudatoolkit as well, e.g.,

`CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA="11.8" mamba install tensorflow cudatoolkit -c conda-forge`

Edit: fixed the command as per the helpful comment!

Comment: Adding  important observation that worked for me was the environment variable `CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA` and not `CONDA_CUDA_OVERRIDE` using `mambaforge`

Comment: This answer worked for me (thanks!) but could anyone explain why this is necessary, specifically in WSL2 as it seems?